# WP Plugin permissions - create new files

Tags: plugins, php, permissions

**Scenario**

1. I'm trying to write to create a file in my plugin directory but I'm getting permission issues on plugin activation.
2. I'm also trying to create/modify a file in the wordpress root directory (it's `ads.txt` so it needs to be in the root dir to work)

**Question**

How can I create both of these files in my WP plugin activation without changing permissions / owners of files?

**Notes**

- I can get past #1 by including empty files at `chmod 666` which I'd much rather leave at `664` - not sure how much of an issue this could be
- I can get past #2 by manually by `chmod theuser:theserver` but of course I want to avoid users needing to do this.

Comment: I always have a define('FS_METHOD','direct'); in my wp-config.php but that's for sure no way to go in production. Why using files instead of pushing it to wp_options table?

Comment: @seot Good point, I could do that for my config but the ads.txt needs to be available for search engines. I could potentially leverage mod rewrite module to make a virtual ads.txt, do you know if that's possible?

Answer (score 0):

I can think here of two possibillites.

1. Use the wp-content/uploads maybe for your text-file because the file
   permission restriction are more or less bypassed in this directory.
2. Put all stuff to wp_options and write a page Template imitating the text-file like page_text.php

   ```
   /* Template Name: Text-Template */ 
   echo get_option('ads', false);
   ```

Create a page and asign the Text-Template and you have a virtual text-file

Comment: So `ads.txt` is an seo though for ads. It HAS to be on the web root for search engines to pick it up. Will option #2 allow for that?